# google pie chart mathemetics

Tags: html, math, google-visualization

I have a tabular data for which I have to create a google pie chart. I did not understand the mathemetics behind the google pie chart creation.

My sample data is::

```
1           600
2           100
3           500
4           300
====================
total       1500
```

In google pie chart, I understood that the total values should be sum to 24. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values do not need to add up to 24, and you do not need to do any math that I am aware of, the library does that automatically.

Your example data would be like this:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Number', 'Value'],
    ['One', 600],
    ['Two', 100],
    ['Three', 500],
    ['Four', 300],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Sample'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```